# INSERT statement syntax with condition and two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to insert the same entries into 2 different tables (which are structurally the same)  on the condition that the current value of a_text in one of the tables is not already present anywhere in that table. Here is my 1st try

```
 cur.execute('''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM checktble WHERE    a_text 
 = %s)   ''', (a_text))THEN INSERT INTO tble1 AND INSERT INTO tble2 
(a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
(a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag))
```

but could someone clean up and fix this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like the following (pseudo code, as I do not have your table strucutre).

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM checktble WHERE a_text = 'yourtexthere')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION doubleInsert
        INSERT INTO tble1 (a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag)
            VALUES ('blabla', 'more blabla', 'linkgoeshere', 'Bla!', 'Source', 'GETDATE(),  'tag';
            INSERT INTO tble2 (a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag)
            VALUES ('blabla', 'more blabla', 'linkgoeshere', 'Bla!', 'Source', 'GETDATE(),  'tag';
    COMMIT TRANSACTION doubleInsert
END
```

Comment: if 'yourtexthere' is a variable name for a string and not an actual string ( i am using python interface) how do i do it?

Comment: I never used Python, but if `IF NOT EXISTS` in the initial code you showed would work, you could replace it with `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

Another that checks in checktable and insert in two table t1 and t2 in a single statement (hence transaction) :

```
insert into t1 (a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag)
    output inserted.a_text, inserted.a_fulltext, inserted.a_link, inserted.a_title, 
            inserted.a_source, inserted.a_date, inserted.a_tag
    into t2(a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag
 SELECT a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag
 from (values
    ( 'myvalue for a_text',... a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag
     )) 
        as T(a_text,a_fulltext,a_link,a_title,a_source,a_date,a_tag) 
 where not exists (select 1 from checktable 
            where checktable.a_text = T.a_text)
```